# jquery ui position of window cause primeui dialog cannot popup after upgrading jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, prime-ui

before i use `jquery 1.10.x`, `jquery ui 1.10.x` and `prime ui 1.1`.

for `prime ui`, there is a dialog widget, its usage like:

```
    jQuery('#div1').puidialog({  
            ...         
            modal: true,  
            width: 600
            ....           
        });
```

then when `jQuery('#div1').puidialog('show');`  is called, there is a dialog pop up and show this div.

However, after I upgrade jquery to `3.4.1` and jquery ui to `1.12.1`, call `jQuery('#div1').puidialog('show');`  cannot show the dialog, there is no errors on console just say `JQMIGRATE: jQuery.isWindow() is deprecated`.

After debug, i found the problem happened in next code of `primeui-1.1.js`:

```
      _initPosition: function() {
            //reset
            this.element.css({left:0,top:0});
           
            if(/(center|left|top|right|bottom)/.test(this.options.location)) {
                this.options.location = this.options.location.replace(',', ' ');

                this.element.position({
                            my: 'center',
                            at: this.options.location,
                            collision: 'fit',
                            of: window,
                            //make sure dialog stays in viewport
                            using: function(pos) {
                                var l = pos.left < 0 ? 0 : pos.left,
                                t = pos.top < 0 ? 0 : pos.top;
                                
                                jQuery(this).css({
                                    left: l,
                                    top: t                                  
                                });
                            }
                        });
            }
            else {
                var coords = this.options.position.split(','),
                x = coords[0].trim(),
                y = coords[1].trim();

                this.element.offset({
                    left: x,
                    top: y
                });
            }

            this.positionInitialized = true;
        }
```

if i remove `of: window` from `this.element.position({...})`, the dialog can be shown, but this dialog is located at `left top`.

that is, after i upgrad jquery from `1.10.x` to `3.4.1`, this primeui dialog cannot be shown. and if i delete `of: window` from `this.element.position({...})`, this primeui dialog will be shown on left top.

what i want is this dialog located on `center` of browser, how can i do that?

Comment: I suspect that `window` will work. You might try replacing it with `$(window)`. It should not matter since the `of` can accept an Object or Element.

Comment: @Twisty unfortunately, `$(window)` doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any other console errors or details?

Comment: @Twisty no other console errors.